# How can I identify the connectors for my stereo?

Tags: electrical, audio

I have a 1996 Volvo 850 and the stereo has two connectors, a rectangular one and a circular plug. Are these connectors to a common standard, or it is some vehicle-specific wiring that need to find a specialized schematic for?

I want to power a 12V computer in the same location, so I need some kind of adapter to power the computer from the stereo connectors.

Comment: A picture would help..

Comment: If you only need the 12V, just get a multimeter and start measuring. But take note, there is a permanent 12V connection, and one switched with your key. You need to take that latter, as that one is meant to deliver power, while the permanent one is only meant to keep momory alive. It's usually fused much lighter.

Answer (score 1):

The rectangular one probably is an [ISO connector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectors_for_car_audio) and the round one is the antenna jack. But yeah, a picture would help.